# How to change the default height of pages and frames in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, geometry

In the Beamer class, is it possible to change the height of a page and frame?
I'm producing a document for web display and would like it to be on a continuously scrolling format so I would like to have frames with height 4 times taller than the current default height. I tried something like the MWE below but I get "Missing \begin{document} error"...

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage[papersize={12cm,30cm}]{geometry}
  \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{test}
   \end{frame}{test}
   \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: The beamer manual clearly states that one should not change the 'paper' size. Perhaps you're looking for something like `beamerarticle` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default page/paper size under [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is 12.8cm wide and 9.6cm tall - a 4:3 ratio - set by [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

If you want something different just set it using `\geometry{..}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{papersize={12.8cm,38.4cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity:  Does Beamer automatically load the geometry package like it does with xcolor or the command \geometry is another animal different from the geometry package?

Comment: @SergioParreiras: [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is loaded by [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), so you're using the same interface.