# How to change geometry with beamer class?

Tags: beamer, geometry

I'd like to change the layout of my slides. For an `article`, the corresponding commands would be `\textheigt` and `\textwidth`, which can be done with `\newgeometry`. When I put these in my presentation, the slides are uncomplete and the top and bottom lines are not at the margin anymore, but I'd like to change the size of the slides themselves, not just their ratio or some positions within the slides.

I also couldn't find any documentation of the `geometry` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\newgeometry{textwidth=10cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or I get the error `"Option clash for package geometry."
"Emergency stop"`.

Comment: documentation:[geometry package](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), Does [How to change the default height of pages and frames in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268563/124842) solves your problem?

Comment: In [beamer.cls](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamer.cls)  geometry is already loaded (see 321). So use `\geometry{margin=1pt}` instead of `\usepackage[margin=1pt]{geometry}`.

Comment: An alternative is to use `\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=10mm} ` -> See:[Modifying the margins of whole slides in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354025/124842)

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Comment: The thing is that the given solution shifts also the bottom line where name of author and title of file appear and the heading so that I get blank space there, which I don't want to have there.
The coloured parts mentioned are supposed to stay at the margins, top and bottom.