# Change the page size in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I am trying to make a set of flashcards using beamer. I want the page size to be well suited for my phone. But I am not able to change the page size of the beamer presentation.

Can you suggest something?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268558/how-to-change-the-default-height-of-pages-and-frames-in-beamer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default height of pages and frames in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268558/how-to-change-the-default-height-of-pages-and-frames-in-beamer)